# Static file error with Heroku and whitenoise - have run collect static

Tags: django, heroku

I redeployed an Django app to heroku, and am now getting static file issues:

`ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'css/styles.min.css'`

I had an error when upgrading boto (used for media files only not static files). So turned collect static off on heroku with:

`heroku config:set DEBUG_COLLECTSTATIC=1`

After fixing the error I manually ran:

`heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput`

to process the static files which produced no issues with the output:
`239 static files copied to '/app/staticfiles', 263 post-processed`

including:
`Post-processed 'css/styles.min.css' as 'css/styles.min.f0168a3a1535.css'`

I reference the file causing the error in my base template with:
`<link href="{% static 'css/styles.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" id="theme-style">`

I am using white noise on heroku with the production settings:

`WHITENOISE_MIDDLEWARE = ('whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware', )
MIDDLEWARE = WHITENOISE_MIDDLEWARE + MIDDLEWARE
WHITENOISE_MAX_AGE = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10  # 10 yrs
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'`

and in requirements have `whitenoise==3.3.1`

I'm not clear what's causing the issue or how best to resolve as I've checked everything I can think of.

Comment: Which Django version are you using?

Comment: I'm using django==1.11.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `collectstatic` using `heroku run` won't work in the way you're expecting it to. Each `heroku run` command runs in its own container and any changes made to the filesystem will be thrown away once the command has finished.

You'll need to re-enable collectstatic and then push a new version of your project to Heroku so that it gets rebuilt.